# DISTINCT is slowing down my queries, multiple columns

Tags: sql

My code looks like this now:

Tables looks like:

```
names surnames  age  gender
adam  lokis     12   m
adam  lokis     12   m
mikel miles     22   m
sara  astin     34   f
```

its sample, i dont know how tables ends, because database is too large

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       one.names,
       two.surnames,
       three.age,
       four.gender
FROM one,two,three,four
WHERE
     four.gender='male'
     group by three.age
```

SQL developer is analyzing those milions of lines for many hours.
I have tried to use `/*+ no_use_hash_aggregation*/` before `DISTINCT` but still have no idea how to make it faster. Maybe good way will be to use `INNER JOIN` between tables?

EDIT: GOT IT !
i've tried an example with two tables only

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       one.names,
       two.surnames,
FROM one INNER JOIN
     two ON one.age=two.age
where
     four.gender='male'
```

Comment: What database? (Tag the correct one).

Comment: As @Simonare points out - shouldn't there be a join condition?

Comment: Stop using comma separated joins, and start using explicit `join` syntax. Then the error is much more apparent. Also, why are you using `group by` when you are not aggregating?

Comment: Yep, use proper joins. Then, if you're still getting "duplicate" rows, the answer is *not* to just throw a `DISTINCT` in there. You should instead examine your join conditions and work out which ones are improperly constrained (or which ones need to compute aggregates in subqueries instead)

Comment: That query is invalid and should raise an error. (Invalid GROUP BY.)

Comment: What does your tables look like? what are the columns? How do they relate to each other? Why are they called one, two three....?

Comment: Our crystal balls are broken, *you*  need to know how to proper join those tables.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that You are making cross join,  ı cannot expect otherwise.

Say that your first table has 10
Second table has 5 
Third table has 6 recorda.

Your query returns

10 x 6 x 5 results.

Use proper joins

Look for

```
İnner join
Left outer join
Right outer join
```

Answer (score 0):

Try join your the tables e.g.

one inner join two on one.id = two.id
inner join three on two.id = three.id.. and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You all have right about JOINS here, INNER JOIN helps me, is case of my previous example this code works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
           one.names,
           two.surnames,
    FROM one INNER JOIN
         two ON one.age=two.age
    where
         four.gender='male'
```